# How can I make a image appear in javascript (and scroll whilst zoomed in)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am very new to JavaScript. I'm trying to create a basic infinite runner game, but I'm stuck on one little issue. I need a image to print out on my HTML canvas, but when I try to nothing happens. I am creating this game with basic JavaScript. No AJAX/jQuery. Here's my code, and what I have tried.

```
//this is my code as of right now for printing images.
function make_base () {
        base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = 'picture.png'
    }
//draw the image to the canvas 2d context
cc.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
```

What this is doing, is nothing. It is not showing any sign of a image. Here's some other code I've gotten, as from w3schools (they're awesome :) )

```
//image source by html hidden element
var img = document.getElementById("picture");
cc.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
</script>
<image src="picture.png" id="picture" hidden></image>
```

This is doing the same thing that the new code is doing. Showing absolutely nothing. I'm not sure why, I've tried with Google Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. All of them with the file uploaded to my website, and with file:///c:/users/name/desktop/js/one.html. Nothing is showing up on the canvas for some strange reason. I've also told Chrome to always use JavaScript. Not only this, but how can I make it zoom in, and scroll from left to right (I can add the blocks/variables that "kill"/make the player restart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to wait for the image to load before trying to draw it.

```js
const c = document.querySelector('canvas')
const cc = c.getContext('2d');

drawImage();

function drawImage() {
  const image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    cc.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
  }
  image.src = "//placecage.com/200/300"
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Also, it's `<img>` not `<image>`.  I haven't checked this, but some browsers don't allow loading things if you're on `file://`, you'll have to spin up a small server and serve from `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! However, this still didn't work on my site. I don't know if it's just my browser, my internet, or my pc in general. It's working on the stackoverflow snippet thing. I'll try on another PC (I have 3). Actually, you did answer, and it worked, so thanks! I'll adjust it to my PCs.

Comment: Be sure to check the console for any errors, and also try [setting up a small server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) as well if you're trying to use local assets.